# Novel - Disguised alien Tock Von visits Earth, meets a girl, gets committed to a psychiatric hospital

Tags: story-identification, novel

I bought this as a new paperback in the early 1970s in the US. I believe there was lots of drug and sex humor I didn't get because I was like 12. I also remember thinking it was the weirdest thing I'd ever read...until I tackled UBIK a couple of years later.  :)

I'm wondering if I'd get the jokes now, and if I'll still think it deserves that high weirdness rating. I've tried searching for the character name with various spellings without success.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This is *The Earth Tripper* by [Leo P. Kelley](https://sf-encyclopedia.com/entry/kelley_leo_p) published in 1973.

From [Goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/2546582.The_Earth_Tripper):

> Story of an apparently quite human-appearing alien who is trapped on
> earth when his means of transportation disappears during a wild
> evening party in the city. He eventually is involuntarily committed to
> a psychiatric institution for his beliefs and activities on earth and
> enters into a contest of wits and more against the staff with the help
> of some of his fellow patients.

From [Amazon](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0006VV32C):

> What would you do... If you saw a man let all the animals out of
> Central park Zoo? Or if you saw the same man take all his clothes off
> and give them to a street derelict? and what would you do if this man
> told you his name was Tock Von and he was from the Planet Eleison in
> the Sixteenth Star System of the Gamma Galaxy? What would you do?
> You'd probably put him away. fast.

[image: Book Cover of The Earth Tripper]

Cover art by [Larry Kresek](https://larrykresek.com/index.html)

Comment: That's the one! I recognized the cover now that I see it. Thank you! LOL even though "Tock Von" is in both the description and the first review, Amazon search doesn't find it. :)

Comment: Honestly, I just googled "Tock Von" (in quotes) and this book was a top 5 result.  I'm glad it's the book you wanted.